# Heroku fork -a (what's -a?)

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Getting familiar with `heroku fork` syntax: `heroku fork -a sourceapp targetapp`

So I attempt to RTM:

```
$ heroku help fork
Usage: heroku fork [NEWNAME]

 Fork an existing app -- copy config vars and Heroku Postgres data, and re-provision add-ons to a new app.
 New app name should not be an existing app. The new app will be created as part of the forking process.

 -s, --stack  STACK   # specify a stack for the new app
 --region REGION      # specify a region
```

No mention of `-a` flag. What does this do? Is it always required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of May 14, 2015 `heroku fork` now expects `--from` and `--to` arguments. The new [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app) is much clearer.

```
heroku fork --from APP_TO_FORK_FROM --to APP_TO_CREATE
```

---

**Original and now wrong answer** with deprecated options for older version of the Heroku toolbelt:

For all heroku commands, `-a` or `--app` is the app that you you want the command to affect. The previous documentation for fork described it thusly:

```
heroku fork -a sourceapp targetapp
```

Without the '-a' flag it infers the app from the current directory or fail and ask you to specify and app or run it from an app directory.

Comment: ah. i'm an idiot. wish they would explicitly state that on the help page. ah well; fun with UNIX.  Thanks!

Comment: the new `--from` ... `--to` syntax makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

This has changed, now the CLI expects `--from` and `--to` instead of `--app`.